# Date calculation differs between a Date object and a Calendar

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

I am writing a code to add amount of days to current date. I have 2 solutions:

**SOLUTION 1**

```
Date current = new Date();

// Add 100 days
Date d = new Date ( current.getTime() + 100 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 );

System.out.println(d);
```

**SOLUTION 2**

```
Date current = new Date();

GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(current);
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 100);

System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

**RESULT**

```
SOLUTION 1: Sat Apr 05 14:56:33 CDT 2014

SOLUTION 2: Sat Apr 05 13:56:33 CDT 2014
```

The result of solution_2 is LESS than result of solution_1 ONE hour.

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Day light savings maybe ?

Comment: The Date class is deprecated, don't use it!

Comment: Don't ever first assume that it's a bug, especially with something so old.

Comment: The `Date` class isn't deprecated... 4/6 of the constructors and a bunch of the methods are, but the class itself isn't and OP isn't using any of the deprecated methods.

Comment: @SamYonnou Oh yeah, silly me :P

Comment: Note that the expression `100 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` overflows. You'll need to use `long` types.

Comment: new Date(long) take long type so I don't think there is overflows here.

Comment: This `100 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` is a bunch of `int` values. Since `*` has priority, the result of this expression will be an `int` that will have overflown. Only when added to the `long` from `current.getTime()` will it be widened to a `long`, but it will be too late.

Answer (score 9):

Solution 2 takes daylight savings into account, whereas solution 1 doesn't. Hence the difference.

On days when there is a transition from summer to winter time, or vice versa, the day isn't 24 hours long as the first method assumes.

Comment: just to add the second method is the one that takes DST into account, the other is just a calculation made manually.

Answer (score 1):

### Daylight Saving Time

Six months from now will cross the beginning of Daylight Saving Time in Lincoln, Nebraska US.

> Sunday, March 9, 2014 at 2:00:00 AM clocks are turned forward 1 hour to
> Sunday, March 9, 2014 at 3:00:00 AM local daylight time instead

http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=132&year=2014

Daylight Saving Time (DST) is one very good reason to avoid doing your own date-time calculations. Use a competent library instead.

### Joda-Time

Neither Solution 1 nor Solution 2 are good. The java.util.Date/Calendar classes are notoriously bad and should be avoided. They are being supplanted in Java 8 by the new [java.time.* classes](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), whose design was inspired by the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

My example code below uses Joda-Time 2.3 running in Java 7.

### Time Zone

Your code fails to address the issue of time zones. Specifying a time zone is a better practice than depending on the default time zone. My example code is using a time zone for Lincoln, NE, US ("America/Indiana/Knox").

### Example Code

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

// Specify a time zone rather than rely on defaults.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Indiana/Knox" );

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( timeZone );
DateTime dateTimeLater = dateTime.plusDays( 100 );

// If you are focusing on the day itself rather than a particular time of day, then use first moment of the day.
DateTime dateTimeStartOfDay = new DateTime( timeZone ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime dateTimeLaterStartOfDay = dateTimeStartOfDay.plusDays( 100 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTimeLater: " + dateTimeLater );
System.out.println( "dateTimeStartOfDay: " + dateTimeStartOfDay );
System.out.println( "dateTimeLaterStartOfDay: " + dateTimeLaterStartOfDay );
System.out.println( "dateTimeLaterStartOfDay in UTC: " + dateTimeLaterStartOfDay.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2013-12-26T23:12:33.527-06:00
dateTimeLater: 2014-04-05T23:12:33.527-05:00
dateTimeStartOfDay: 2013-12-26T00:00:00.000-06:00
dateTimeLaterStartOfDay: 2014-04-05T00:00:00.000-05:00
dateTimeLaterStartOfDay in UTC: 2014-04-05T05:00:00.000Z
```

### Convert To j.u.Date

If you need to convert to a java.util.Date for use with other code, call the `toDate` method.

```java
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```